# Remove duplicates in Bitwarden

Tags: passwords, password-management

I have imported three sets of entries (passwords) into Bitwarden, each stored in a separate folder. Is there a method to remove duplicate items in bulk? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/elias123tre/bitwarden_find_duplicates

Comment: Thanks @Gantendo. The script works for listing but still not be able to "remove" part, any workaround by chance?